# Why can't I upload my XML data to a OneDrive file in Android?

Tags: android, xml, onedrive

I've been trying to upload XML data containing user profiles to my OneDrive account using my Android app.

No matter what example code I find on the internet my app doesn't upload any data.  Ideally I'd like to keep my code as simple as possible (I'm still very inexperienced) but maybe it's simply not possible to achieve this without installing plugins & SDK packs for OneDrive?  Is there another file hosting service (Google Drive, Drop Box, etc) where this sort of simple code would work?  Thanks in advance!

The code I'm trying to use is below:

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class UploadProfileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private TextView textView;
public UploadProfileTask(TextView textView) {
    this.textView = textView;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        return uploadUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        return "Xml error. URL may be invalid.";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Connection error. URL may be invalid.";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "Parse error. URL may be invalid.";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textView.setText(result);
}


private String uploadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, ParseException {

    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Get the user profile as an XML string.
        String param = Globals.SerializeProfile;
        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(param);
        out.close();

        String response= "";

        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

        while(inStream.hasNextLine())
            response+=(inStream.nextLine());

    }
    catch(MalformedURLException ex){
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
    }

    return "Profile uploaded successfully";

}
```

}

Comment: Please paste your errors if you have any.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors, it's just that no data gets uploaded.